# cannot find crt1.o No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation

I am trying to compile and link a 32 bit version of a program because the language does not have 64 bit libraries. My ubuntu is 14.04 64 bit. When I try to link the program it complains **cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory**. I found the 64 bit `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o` file on my computer but no 32 bit version. What do I need to be able to link both 64 and 32 programs.

Comment: Did you install the `gcc-multilib` package? I think that's what (indirectly) provides it

Comment: Note that `crt1.o` and `crti.o` are Not The Same.

Answer (score 2):

On my system, I have both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of `crt1.o`:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o;dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
libc6-dev:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

`crt1.o` is in the `libc6-dev` package for the appropriate architecture.

Comment: Those are the 32 and 64 bit files. My question remains, what do I need to install to add the 32bit?

Comment: Read `man dpkg`. The package to install is `libc6-dev:i386`.